# Xcode5 image assets landscape/portrait image

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I use the new feature of Xcode 5 - media assets.
I want to add portrait and landscape image for iPad. 
For selected image there is only option to add retina and non retina, no option for landscape and portrait.
Is there any way to add landscape and portrait for one image?

Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

you can use autosizing with that view. when lanscape or portrait it will be expand or collapse imageView